# LEFT JOIN Query With Condition

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that LEFT JOINS another table to group rows. I am trying to only select records from the first table "googleimage" where the user_id is a certain number. (user_id is a column in "googleimage" table.

```
SELECT g.*
FROM googleimage g
LEFT JOIN (SELECT image_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM googleimagefound WHERE status = 0
GROUP BY image_id) gf ON gf.image_id = g.id
ORDER BY  COALESCE(cnt, 0) DESC");
```

I have tried adding a new ON statement beiside the

```
gf ON gf.image_id = g.id
```

I have also tried changing

```
SELECT g.*
FROM googleimage g
```

to

```
SELECT g.*
FROM googleimage WHERE user_id = 1 g
```

but none of them seem to work, any help will be appriciated

Comment: are you getting any errors? if so post them

Answer (score 2):

Try changing you query a bit like below

```
SELECT g.*
FROM googleimage g
LEFT JOIN (SELECT image_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM googleimagefound WHERE status = 0
GROUP BY image_id) gf ON gf.image_id = g.id
WHERE g.user_id = 1 <-- add this condition
ORDER BY  COALESCE(gf.cnt, 0) DESC;
```

Comment: Please explain what and why did you do ?

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com, few thing are self explanatory and need not write an essay to explain. Moreover, I am not here to teach A,B,C,D,..... See answer properly where i have pointed what i have added to the query. That should be enough to my knowledge.

Comment: @user3439600, if the answer really helped then consider accepting it.